# always prompt the user before executing a command in the shell

Tags: bash, command-line

Is there a utility that always prompts the user for confirmation before executing a command similar to the way `sudo` asks for password?

Comment: Do you really want that for any command? Including `cd` and `ls`?

Comment: I'd like to have it in my own aliases in .bashrc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you want it to work without typing an extra command, e.g.

```
$ rm file
```

Or only when the user types something like

```
$ confirm rm file
```

Or only when the user tries to run certain commands, e.g.

```
$ rm file
```

but not for

```
$ echo "Hello"
```

If option 1, that can be done using the preexec hook in zsh, or the DEBUG trap in bash.

If option 2, put something like this in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or other shell startup file.

```
confirm() {
    echo -n "Do you want to run $*? [N/y] "
    read -N 1 REPLY
    echo
    if test "$REPLY" = "y" -o "$REPLY" = "Y"; then
        "$@"
    else
        echo "Cancelled by user"
    fi
}
```

If option 3, you could modify the `confirm` script above, or, some commands have an option to ask before doing something, e.g. `rm -i`.   You could put 
`alias rm='rm -i'` in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: I would like the confirmation only for one single command that always gives me headache. How would the script look like?

Answer (score 10):

I have played with bash a bit and figured out a hack by which this could be made possible.

```
#!/bin/bash

debug_trap () {
    echo "executing $BASH_COMMAND"
    echo "Allow?"
    select choice in yes no
    do
        if [ "$choice" = "yes" ]
        then break
        elif [ "$choice" = "no" ]
        then return 1
        fi
    done
}

shopt -s extdebug
trap debug_trap DEBUG
```

You can save this script under, say, `confirm-any-command.sh` and `source` it in your `bashrc`. It will ask for confirmation of each command you will try to execute.

Please note that this is nothing more than a proof-of-concept hack; I doubt it can really be any useful in this form. If you will have to confirm each and every command you type, you will very soon acquire a habit to automatically hit "yes" after each command. Your mental mapping for "end of command" will change from just <kbd>Enter</kbd> to <kbd>Enter</kbd>,<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> - you will be typing it as a whole, don't even trying to spend some time on verifying that you *really* want this command to execute. This is counterproductive and won't help you.

Comment: Stops on `Allow?
1) yes
2) no
#? 
` neither `yes` nor `no` work causing infinite loop (Debian 8)

Comment: @vladkras read `help select`: you're supposed to input `1` or `2` rather than `yes` or `no`. The automatic retry for invalid inputs is intended behavior (so that the script writer doesn't have to reinvent a `while` herself, retaining conciseness and clarity), and  EOF input terminates the loop. Knowing that, you can check yourself that the script above works. I won't be modifying it, since it's a crude proof of concept anyway.

Comment: that's true. I was confused by your `y e s Enter` example

Answer (score 0):

First, open the terminal.

Then, type

```
cd ~
touch .sure
chmod 700 .sure
```

Next, open .sure and paste this inside.

```
#!/bin/bash --init-file
PS1='> '
alias y='
    $1
    exit
'
alias n='killall Terminal'
echo ''
echo 'Are you sure? Answer y or n.'
echo ''
```

After that, close the file.

```
~/.sure ; ENTER COMMAND HERE
```

This will give you a prompt of are you sure before continuing the command.